# Search for 1D np array in 3D np array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

In the following example I am trying to search for 1D np array in a 3D np array.

```
import numpy as np


a = np.array([[[1, 2], [3, 4]],
              [[5, 6], [3, 2]],
              [[2, 1], [7, 8]]])

b = np.array([1, 2])

print(np.all(a == b, axis=1))
# print(np.where(np.all(a == b, axis=(1,1))))
```

The result I get is the following:

```
[[False False]
 [False False]
 [False False]]
```

Which means I get correct dimensions for the boolean table, but for some reason the result is not the expected one.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `axis=2`, i.e the 3rd axis:

```
np.all(a == b, axis=2)

[[ True False]
 [False False]
 [False False]]
```

Or you can specify `axis=-1` for the last axis:

```
np.all(a == b, axis=-1)

[[ True False]
 [False False]
 [False False]]
```